# Google chrome won't connect to the internet on mobile data

Tags: chrome-for-android

This site can’t be reached

m.facebook.com refused to connect

---

1. No issues browsing the net on Chrome using WiFi
2. No issues browsing the net on Firefox using mobile/WiFi
3. No issues installing app for the play store (I installed Firefox to test) using mobile/WiFi
4. Can receive non-SMS messages (example: WhatsApp) using mobile/WiFi
5. Can make phone calls
6. Clearing chrome data did not do anything
7. No VPN active right now

Answer (score 0):

Consider reinstalling chrome. Because something it happens error while downloading . May be the script in there somewhere is corrupted. Sometimes reinstall help

Comment: The reasoning provided for reinstalling Chrome is pretty vague. Can you link where this error or script is discussed or reported and that reinstallation is the answer? Also, how does reinstallation would help over clearing data files?